# Alert dialog view is set incorrectly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I have an alert dialog with `EditText` wrapped in `TextInputLayout`. The following works fine

```
builder.setView(R.layout.input_dialog)
```

[image]

But since I want to get a reference to the edit text, when I try the following, the `TextInputLayout` is gone and only the edit text is left. What have I done wrong?

```
val input = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.input_dialog, null)
builder.setView(input)
```

[image]

#### input_dialog.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:hintEnabled="false"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

#### activity

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert)
```

Comment: What is **input_dialog_single**?

Comment: A typo, sorry it wasn't the problem

Comment: instead of null try to add the root of the layout as viewgroup in inflate method..

Comment: @AalapPatel, the root layout of activity or dialog? How to get it

Comment: root of activity, in your activity.xml, give ID to the root layout and use it here and see what happens, I also want to know that this edit text doesnt appear or you dont have focus on it ?? i.e. if you click there you dont see the edit text focus .. ???

Comment: got you. No it's just not there, even when I focus on it and start typing

Comment: @AalapPatel, tried, the problem remains

Comment: @JGuo How can you start tying without an EditText ?

Comment: EditText is there, I can type, but just no underline no cursor nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that once I remove the `TextInputLayout` and leave just `EditText`, everything works. `TextInputLayout` doesn't seem to work properly in alert dialog for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to change `R.layout.input_dialog_single` to `R.layout.input_dialog`

Comment: A typo, sorry. It wasn't the problem